# how to change the max count of columns in one row depending on the size screen

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

by default, bootstrap has 12 columns. I need 8 columns on md and 4 columns on sm(all) screen.
The code below doesn't split columns in the right way on md screen (768px), the second column doesn't fit in the row. And there are 12 columns, not 8

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-cols-12 row-cols-md-8">
    <div class="col-md-5 bg-primary">Column</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 bg-secondary">Column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap uses 12 columns. you can get 8 columns by using containing columns. I would help with that, but I don't really get how wide you want the 2 divs.

Comment: I find myself agreeing with Gert. In my brain you should simply be able to use `col-md-8 col-sm-4` and this will achieve 8 columns on anything medium screens and above but 4 columns on small screens. Just a normal row with a single column in it that has a both medium and a small setting.

Comment: I want to use 8 as the maximum. therefore 3 and 5 should be full-page.

Comment: ok, I get it. thanks for explanation